# p:selectOneMenu при изменении не обновляет кнопку

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

Есть два списка и кнопка. Первый список - страны, второй - города. При изменении страны изменяется список городов. тут все ок. При изменении города должна стать доступной кнопка, если перевыбрать страну - перестраивается список городов выбранной страны. Все ок. При выборе города, кнопка становится доступной, НО, если выбрать первый элемент списка городов, не срабатывает {ajax} и кнопка все равно остается доступной.

```
<p:panelGrid columns="3">
 <p:selectOneMenu value="#{addNewTaskBean.selectedCountry}" 
     id="ant_selected_country" converter="countryConverter">

     <p:ajax update="ant_selected_locality ant_detail_map_label" 
             event="itemSelect" listener="#{addNewTaskBean.resetLocality()}"/>

     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select country" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
     <f:selectItems value="#{applicationUtilsBean.countryList}" 
                    var="cntry" itemLabel="#{cntry.name}"
                    itemValue="#{cntry.dbID}"/>
 </p:selectOneMenu>                               

 <p:selectOneMenu value="#{addNewTaskBean.locality}" 
                  id="ant_selected_locality" converter="localityConverter"
                  valueChangeListener="#{addNewTaskBean.onLocalityChange}">

      <p:ajax update="ant_detail_map_label" event="change"/>

      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select locality" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />

      <f:selectItems value="#{addNewTaskBean.selectedCountry.localities}" var="locality"
                    itemLabel="#{locality.description}"
                    itemValue="#{locality.dbID}"/>

 </p:selectOneMenu>                               

 <p:commandButton id="ant_detail_map_label"
                  value="Подробно..."
                  onclick="PF('ant_detail_map_dlg').show();" 
                  disabled="#{!addNewTaskBean.localitySelected}" widgetVar="ant_detail_map_label">

     <pe:tooltip for="ant_detail_map_label" >
         <h:outputText value="Вы можете более точно указать место на карте." style="font-size: 0.5em"/>
     </pe:tooltip>
  </p:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Явно установите `null` для первого значения:

```
 <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select locality" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
```

Comment: все равно не работает. увы. Причем, что интересно, если устанавливаю страну в положение "Выберите страну" - срабатывает

Comment: больше того, если сделать аджакс запрос по аналогии со списком стран, указав листенер по событию itemSelect, тогда другая беда - метод бина срабатывает только для выбранных городов, т.е. если выбрать город - зайду в метод бина, а если выберу первый пункт - даже не заходит в метод бина

Comment: Убедитесь, что переменная `localitySelected` принимает нужное значение. В компоненте меню у вас указано `value="#{addNewTaskBean.locality}"`

Comment: спасибо. Надо было взглянуть на класс заново… когда долго сидишь за одной и той же проблемой, пропускаешь банальности…